# Hibernate: What is the best way to perform 'bitwise and' operation?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I my project I am using hibernate (3.5.6) to interact with db.. I am using DetachedCriteria and projections API to form my general queries.

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(<ClassName>.class,"rp");
detachedCriteria.setProjection(Projections.count("<field>"));
detachedCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("<field>", field));
count = (Long) getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(detachedCriteria).get(0);
```

Now I want to perform '**bitwise and**' operation over values.. I can use the same methods to perform this 'bitwise and' operation.. If not what is the best way to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the solution myself..

Key thing is to extend the default 'Dialect' to you custom dialect and register your custom method for the bitwise and operation

```
public class MySQLDialect extends org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect {
    public MySQLDialect() {
       super();
       registerFunction("bitwise_and", new MySQLBitwiseAndSQLFunction("bitwise_and", Hibernate.INTEGER));
   }
}
```

Here is the link with full explanation: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=940978

Cheers :)..